# MongoDB aggregation with spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to create a ranking of games based on reviews. I'm trying to get average of stars and group it by games. This is how my collection looks like:

```
{
  "_id": "31f6f1a8-4bfb-4753-b2d4-0acc296c3d91",
  "title": "Cool game.",
  "description": "The best game ever.",
  "stars": 4,
  "game": "xxx",
  "_class": "com.example.demo.model.Review"
}
```

This is what I did in Spring:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ranking")
public List<Review> getRanking() {


    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(group("game").avg("stars").as("average"),
        project("average").and("game").previousOperation());
    AggregationResults<Review> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "reviews", Review.class);
    List<Review> finalResult = results.getMappedResults();
    return finalResult;
```

And this is what I get in Postman:

```
    "id": null,
    "title": null,
    "description": null,
    "stars": null,
    "game": "xxx"
```

How should I change my code to get only average of stars for every game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$game",
      "stars": {
        "$avg": "$stars"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4yMlgWUPx-V)

**EDIT:**

You are projecting the average of stars as `average` field in query. But i think there is no `average` field in `Review.java`. Hence it is showing null.

What you can do is project the average of stars as `stars` like so :-

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(group("game").avg("stars").as("stars"),
        project("stars").and("game").previousOperation());
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to transform that query to java language (as above) but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Can you share Review.java?

Comment: As I changed it to that form, it worked: 
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(group("game").avg("stars").as("stars"), project("stars").and("game").previousOperation());

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I didn't know that problem is with name average